# Different between join with "\n" and join with '\n' in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a list of all image names, now i want to join it by newline before run so i did this:

```
print (join '\n', @all_img_name);
```

The above line will produce this kind of output:

> `meomeo_0\nmeomeo_1\nmeomeo_2\nmeomeo_3\nmeomeo_4\nmeomeo_5\nmeomeo_6\nmeomeo_7\nmeomeo_8\nmeomeo_9\nmeomeo_10\nmeomeo_11\nmeomeo_12\nmeomeo_13\nmeomeo_14\nmeomeo_15`

while if i do this, i get everything right:

```
print (join "\n", @all_img_name);
```

What is the difference between those two ways?

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `join`. Compare `print '\n'` and `print "\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

In single quotes, only `\'` and `\\` are special.

In double quotes, many character combinations have special meaning. We say that double quotes are "interpolating". See "Quote and Quote-like Operators" in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop) for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is about creating quoted strings. It has nothing to do with `join()`.

From [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> String literals are usually delimited by either single or double
>   quotes. They work much like quotes in the standard Unix shells:
>   double-quoted string literals are subject to backslash and variable
>   substitution; single-quoted strings are not (except for "\'" and
>   "\"). The usual C-style backslash rules apply for making characters
>   such as newline, tab, etc., as well as some more exotic forms. See
>   "Quote and Quote-like Operators" in perlop for a list.

Following the advice to read [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators), we find this list which tells us which quote-like operators interpolate variables and C-style escape sequences (like `\n`):

> ```
> Customary  Generic        Meaning          Interpolates
> ''         q{}            Literal          no
> ""         qq{}           Literal          yes
> ``         qx{}           Command          yes*
>            qw{}           Word list        no
> //         m{}            Pattern match    yes*
>            qr{}           Pattern          yes*
>            s{}{}          Substitution     yes*
>            tr{}{}         Transliteration  no (but see below)          
>            y{}{}          Transliteration  no (but see below)
>            <<EOF          here-doc         yes*
>
> * unless the delimiter is ''.
> ```

And this list of escape sequences:

> ```
> Sequence     Note  Description
> \t                  tab               (HT, TAB)
> \n                  newline           (NL)
> \r                  return            (CR)
> \f                  form feed         (FF)
> \b                  backspace         (BS)
> \a                  alarm (bell)      (BEL)
> \e                  escape            (ESC)
> \x{263A}     [1,8]  hex char          (example: SMILEY)
> \x1b         [2,8]  restricted range hex char (example: ESC)
> \N{name}     [3]    named Unicode character or character sequence
> \N{U+263D}   [4,8]  Unicode character (example: FIRST QUARTER MOON)
> \c[          [5]    control char      (example: chr(27))
> \o{23072}    [6,8]  octal char        (example: SMILEY)
> \033         [7,8]  restricted range octal char  (example: ESC)
> ```

(I've omitted the notes - they can be found at the link above.)

Summarising all of that, the answer to your question is that `\n` (along with most other C-style escape sequences) are expanded in double-quoted strings and not in single-quoted strings.

This is a feature that Perl shares with many (probably most) other programming languages.